# Why does adipic acid give a cyclic ketone on heating while glutaric acid and succinic acid give a cyclic anhydride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

Why does adipic acid give cyclic ketone on heating while glutaric and succinic acid give cyclic anhydride?

[image]

Comment: It's different reaction, with Ba(OH)2. I guess you should find more precise source of information.

Comment: Seven-rings are notoriously unstable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketonic_decarboxylation and http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV1P0192

Comment: The calcium salt of adipic acid also works. Essentially a Dieckmann cyclization with decarboxylation. Been there. Done it. No metal salt needed with succinic and glutaric acid.

Comment: @RitwikDas Can you specify the source? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to Blanc Rule for Dibasic Carboxylic acids, A cyclic Ketone is formed unless a five or six membered cyclic acid anhydride can be formed. This rule is valid for 1,4; 1,5; 1,6. dicarboxylic acids

Answer (score -1):

Because cyclic anhydride formed will be a 7 Member ring compound which is less stable than 5 membered cyclic ketone

Comment: Can you please cite some sources? Also, note that the rings are substituted. Btw, welcome to Chem.SE!